# Using multiple shared service subscriptions in one component in Angular

Tags: angular

In Angular, I am using multiple shared service to pass props to some components. In my ngInit, I am subscribing to each of these shared services and making my api call whenever there is value, but I just realized, if two values change, it makes the API call twice and then it is random which information loads later is the one that loads.

```
this._sharedService.sharedData1.subscribe(value => {
  if (value) {
    this.data1 = value;
    //API call w/ value 1
  }
})

this._sharedService.sharedData2.subscribe(value => {
  if (value) {
    this.data2 = value;
    //API call w/ value 1 & value 2
  }
})
```

But when sharedData 1 loads later, then my API call is only made with data 1 and not with both data 1 and data 2. I need all my shared services to register their values before making this API call. But if I make my API call outside of the subscription, it won't register except ONLY on init. Doesn't register when my sharedService gets a new value.

Any help please? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe something like combineLatest is your friend?

Comment: ReplaySubject can save value before subscribe. [link document] (https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject)